# What does "sensitive" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Some headaches can be cured by a **sensitive** finger-pressure massage.
>   The massage should be given on sensitive "trigger" points. There are
>   three pairs of points: one at each temple, one under each shoulder
>   blade, and a pair at the back of the neck. Press each point for 15 to
>   30 seconds at a time. Remember to press both points in a pair at the
>   same time, not just one side. Doing this will help the body's natural
>   painkillers start working. If you are alone, press the thumb of one
>   hand against the tender spot in the "V" formed by the thumb and
>   forefinger of the other hand.

Source: [**Headache Away**](http://media.open.edu.cn/media_file/netcourse/asx/zhyy3/unit/unit9/kwyy/menu.htm)

`Sensitive` in the first line seems to refer to `massage`. But what does `sensitive massage` mean? I've already looked up `sensitive` in some dictionaries, but none of the senses seem to apply in this context. Please let me know what dictionary you used to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Sensitive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sensitive)***  here means:

> - (Physiology) of or relating to the senses or the power of sensation.

The expression [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sensitive%20massage&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csensitive%20massage%3B%2Cc0) appears to have been used from the '80s, probably with the spread of orieantal practices.

From [Spa Style Europe](https://books.google.it/books?id=lCIJiUIthJYC&q=%22sensitive%20massage%22&dq=%22sensitive%20massage%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6-4OU4MrPAhXLOhQKHQYGBtkQ6AEIKjAD):

> - ... treatments Ayurveda facials with neck and head massage, Ayurvedic treatments; body cocoons with hay, mare's milk, honey and evening primrose oil; Esalen Bodywork, Lomi Lomi Nui Massage, Shiatsu and ***Intuitive Sensitive Massage,***  ...